# Trying to split strings into key:value pairs and sum the values

Tags: python

I have a list of items and the number of that item sold separated by a colon `:`. The item can exist multiple times within the list. The end goal is to create a dataframe with the item listed in one column and the total number sold in the other column. I was thinking of splitting the list into a dictionary creating key:value pairs out of the item and number sold. Then converting this dictionary into a dataframe. I'm getting hung up on summing the values when the item appears more than once. Below is the data, what I tried, and the result.

```
orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]
my_dict = dict(s.split(":") for s in orders)
print(my_dict)
# {'screws': '15', 'nails': '20', 'brushes': '5'}
```

The result I want is `{'screws' : '35', 'nails': '35', 'brushes': '5'}` and then convert that into a df.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a dict, but you would have to handle missing keys. Instead use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which automatically treats a missing value as `0`.

```
from collections import Counter

tally = Counter()
for s in orders:
    item, count = s.split(":")
    tally[item] += int(count)
print(tally)  # -> Counter({'screws': 35, 'nails': 35, 'brushes': 5})
```

You could also use `defaultdict(int)`, but `Counter` is the better tool for the job.

Comment: It might not matter here but `defaultdict` is *by far* faster than a `Counter`.

Comment: @jan How can that be? Aren't they practically the same?

Comment: `Counter` really has more functions and thus overhead. Look into my answer for a comparison. It might really not matter though as I have tested it for a 100.000 cycles.

Comment: @Jan Yeah it looks like it's just construction that takes a while. If you make it so that the list is longer, they start to even out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary like so:

```
d = {}

for s in orders:
    key, value = s.split(":")
    d[key] = d.get(key, 0) + int(value)

print (d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assembling your data into a `list` instead of a `dict`.  With a `dict` rows with duplicate names will be clobbered.

Also, you'll have to convert your counts to integers before you can sum them.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]

items_0 = [s.split(':') for s in orders]
items = [[item[0], int(item[1])] for item in items_0]  # convert counts to integer

# create the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Item', 'Count'])

# show the data frame
print(df)
# print again, summing the counts for each item
print(df.groupby('Item').sum())
```

which prints

```
      Item  Count
0   screws     20
1    nails     15
2  brushes      5
3   screws     15
4    nails     20
         Count
Item          
brushes      5
nails       35
screws      35
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a big for loop for my solution, sorry if you're trying to avoid them:

```
orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]
my_dict = dict()

for s in orders:
    key, value = s.split(':')
    if key in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[key] += int(value)
        continue
    my_dict[key] = int(value)
print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]
dct = defaultdict(int)

for item in orders:
    key, value = item.split(":")
    dct[key] += int(value)

print(dct)
```

Which yields

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'screws': 35, 'nails': 35, 'brushes': 5})
```

---

Timing `Counter` vs. a simple `defaultdict` shows:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import timeit

orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]

def solution_wjandrea():
    tally = Counter()
    for s in orders:
        item, count = s.split(":")
        tally[item] += int(count)
    return tally

def solution_jan():
    dct = defaultdict(int)

    for item in orders:
        key, value = item.split(":")
        dct[key] += int(value)
    return dct

print(timeit.timeit(solution_wjandrea, number=10**6))
print(timeit.timeit(solution_jan, number=10**6))
```

This yields (on my Macbook Air):

```
6.034431410000001
3.8878112820000004
```

Comment: And using the vanilla dict has a slight edge on defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary keys have to be unique. So, when you loop through the element in list, if the key is duplicated, the value is replaced by the "new" value. What you'd need is to be able to convert the values into integers, and then add them as you loop through.

If you want the values to be string, you may need to use `str`  but it sounds like you'd like to use the resulting dict as a dataframe.

```
orders = ["screws:20", "nails:15", "brushes:5", "screws:15", "nails:20"]
my_dict = {i.split(":")[0]:i.split(":")[1] for i in orders}
my_dict = {}

for elem in orders:
    key, value = elem.split(":")
    if key not in my_dict:
        my_dict[key] = 0
    my_dict[key] += int(value)



print(my_dict)
>>>{'screws': 35, 'nails': 35, 'brushes': 5}
```

If you use pandas to create pandas dataframe or series from there.